# Linking Curl to Windows Runtime VC++ Project [UWP 10 Mobile App]

Tags: curl, visual-c++, windows-runtime, libcurl

am trying to link curl in a C++ Windows Runtime Component Project . I did the following 1. Installed curl packages from nugget . So referenced Packages are rmt_curl, rmt_openssl, rmt_libssh2, openssl, rmt_zlib, zlib, libssh2, curl. 2. Preprocess Defintions I added WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, CURL_STATIC_LIB . I did not add static library dependency because: a. I could not find libcurl.lib compiled for ARM platform. 2. Because I installed it through nugget.

Error

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol curl_easy_init referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl WindowsRuntimeComponent2::Class1::[WindowsRuntimeComponent2::__IClass1PublicNonVirtuals]::test(void)" (?test@?Q__IClass1PublicNonVirtuals@WindowsRuntimeComponent2@@Class1@2@U$AAAXXZ) WindowsRunentimeComponent2 c:\Users\Abhishek\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsRuntimeComponent2\WindowsRuntimeComponent2\Class1.obj

Can somebody please help. Attached in the screenshot of project settings.

[Vc++ Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIZpD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but it's CURL_STATICLIB not CURL_STATIC_LIB